# Title page line spacing in Latex

Tags: line-spacing

I use this code on my title page:

```
{\large {Some College \\ Some Place \\ Some City}} \par}
```

The first two lines get normal spacing, but the third line gets little more bigger spacing. How can I have equal space between all the three lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

compare:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

{\large {Some College \\ Some Place \\ Some City}} \par

\bigskip
{\large {Some College \\ Some Place \\ Some City} \par}% the inenr {} are useless

\bigskip
{\large Some College \\ Some Place \\ Some City \par}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

End the line after the city, before the scope of `\large` ends:

```
{{\large {Some College \\ Some Place \\ Some City}} \par}
```

If the line or paragraph break happens after the scope of `\large` has ended, that size declaration would not have an effect on the line spacing.